# What are the disadvantages to the use of "umbrella" headers in C projects?

Tags: c, include

I saw an interesting pattern in a C project: they used an umbrella header (a header that includes everything from a component) everywhere, inside the component itself too.

umbrella.h:

```
#include "component_file1.h"
#include "component_file2.h"
/* #include each and every header of the component */
```

component_file1.h:

```
#include "umbrella.h"
/*include guard and header*/
```

component_file1.c:

```
#include "umbrella.h"
/*c code*/
```

The pattern was the same in the other files. The explanation I got was:

1. Compilation time did not matter in that project
2. It was easy to use (no need to know header hierarchy)

An additional technical detail: In umbrella.h they sorted the include directives to solve internal dependencies (for e.g. if component_file_2.h used component_file_1.h their order was: component_file_1.h first then component_file_2.h later)

Aside from compilation time, are there any serious drawbacks to this approach that would counter-indicate its use? On what criteria could a refactor of code that used this approach be justified?

Comment: Comments have been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190543/discussion-on-question-by-broothy-in-c-use-umbrella-headers-internally). I'm re-opening this after an edit clarified that it's not just soliciting opinions. Many programming questions are naturally going to involve opinions, especially those about structure and design. The key is that we want *supported* opinions, based on facts and expertise. I see no reason why this question should be off-topic for Stack Overflow. Answers to it can be judged by objective criteria.